Optimizing Location-Based Data Analysis System Schema in PostgreSQL
Preface:
I am developing an analytics application designed for businesses operating across different geographical locations. This application allows users to analyze data based on their associated locations within a hierarchical structure. The system is built using PostgreSQL and Node.js (NestJS).
Issue:
I need to design the database schema in the most optimized manner, with a focus on flexibility in location hierarchy and efficient filtering of data based on location.
Current Schema Example:
Model Hierarchy:
Id (PK): Primary key
order: number indicating the higher order
label: String describing the level of hierarchy

Model Location:
location_id (PK): Primary key
hierarchy_id: Foreign key referencing the Hierarchy table
parent_id: References the location_id of the parent location
Name: name of that location

Model User:
User_id (PK): Primary key
location_ids: Array of location_ids associated with the user
LocationAccess: Array of Location objects representing the user's access rights

Model Leads:
Id (PK): Primary key
location_id: References the location_id of the branch/shop where the sale was made
location: Location object representing the end branch/shop

Example Data:
Model Hierarchy:
| Id | order | label |
+----+-------+----------+
| 1 | 1 | Country |
| 2 | 2 | State |
| 3 | 3 | District |
| 4 | 4 | Shop |

Model Location:
| location_id | hierarchy_id | parent_id |name           |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+-----------+
| 1           | 1              | null       |INDIA         |
| 2           | 2              | 1          |Delhi         |
| 3           | 3              | 2          | Gurwan       |
| 4           | 4              | 3          | Bansal sales |

Model User:
| User_id | location_ids | LocationAccess |
+-------------+--------------+-------------------+
| 1         | [1, 2]       | [1, 2]          |
| ...       | ...          | ...             |

Model Leads:
+-------------+--------------+-------------------+
| Id          | location_id  | location_location_id|
+-------------+--------------+-------------------+
| 1           | 4            | 4                 |
| ...         | ...          | ...               |
Approaches:

Approach 1: Use a recursive query to retrieve data for any user by
fetching all possible location_ids from the Location table. And the
use (leads in (array)) query to fetch data However, this approach is
not efficient as a user with higher order may have up to 400 location
access.

Approach 2: Add a computed column to the Leads table containing
parent_location_ids. This column is updated whenever the hierarchy
changes. Retrieve all parent locations and store them in this column,
then use them in an array for filtering. Like where
parent_location_ids in user_array_locations This approach is more
efficient compared to Approach 1.

Approach 3  create a column in location with string example "1-2-3" then use like
operator on this


Issues with Approach 2:
Querying for data grouped by a certain hierarchy can be complex and inefficient in this structure. As users have the option to group by all the given hierarchies.
Seeking Solutions:

Is there a better approach to optimize data retrieval based on
location hierarchy? Has anyone implemented a similar solution?

Are there any PostgreSQL features or custom data types that can
improve    query efficiency in this context? e.g., create a custom
location    object that can store all hierarchy items with the
hierarchy label in    it.


